# show localized in-app purchase price when I move in my controller

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, uialertview

I want to show localized price when I move in my controller.

I use this code:

```
if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments())
            {
                let productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: self.product_id!)
                let productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
                productsRequest.delegate = self
                productsRequest.start()
                print("Fetching Products")
            }else{
                print("Can't make purchases")
            }

func productsRequest (_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {

    let count : Int = response.products.count
    if (count>0) {
        let validProduct: SKProduct = response.products[0] as SKProduct
        if (validProduct.productIdentifier == self.product_id) {
            buyProduct(product: validProduct);

        } else {
            print(validProduct.productIdentifier)
        }
    } else {
        print("nothing")
    }
}

func buyProduct(product: SKProduct){
    price = localizedPriceForProduct(product)
    let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment);
    self.loading.stopAnimating()
}

func localizedPriceForProduct(_ product:SKProduct) -> String {
    let priceFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    priceFormatter.formatterBehavior = NumberFormatter.Behavior.behavior10_4
    priceFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.currency
    priceFormatter.locale = product.priceLocale
    return priceFormatter.string(from: product.price)!
}
```

But in this case I see UIAlertView with login in the store. How to fix it and disappear this UIAlertView?

Comment: Why are you calling `buyProduct` from your `productRequests` delegate method?  This initiates  purchase, somthe user is promoted for their account details.

Comment: @Paulw11 If I want to show price I need to call `productRequests :`. And if user click on button to purchase (this button activate `productRequests :`) I need call `productRequests :` Where I need call `buyProduct` to user can be purchase.

Comment: You would typically display the products you have retrieved in a tableview or some other UI and then call `buyProduct` when the user selects the product they want to buy.

Comment: @Paulw11 What I should change in code?

Comment: Remove the call to `buyProduct` from the request delegate method. You should retrieve the products either when your app starts or when you want to display your store interface.

Comment: @Paulw11 How I can call `buyProduct` in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: You wouldn't. You would call `buyProduct` when the user taps the buy button associated with that product

Comment: @Paulw11 And how can I call `buyProduct` in button action?

Comment: I don't understand that question. You just call it.

Comment: @Paulw11 in `productRequests ` I call `buyProduct ` like this `buyProduct(product: validProduct)`. In my button action `@IBAction func buttonAction(sender: AnyObject) {}` I call `buyProduct ` like this `buyProduct(product: what I should write here?)`

Comment: That is correct, but you shouldn't be surprised when the user is prompted for their password